# How to delete unfinished installations on Windows 10 Mobile (Lumia 550)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, storage, lumia-550

After some failed updates on the phone, Storage usage is:

- System & reserved: 2,94 GB
- Apps & games: 1,27 GB ( of which nothing can be removed)
- Temporary files: 2,94 GB ( of which pending updates and preview builds is taking up alls 2,94 GB)

Is there any way to delete those temporary files? (without trying to get full file system access, which seems to be suggested when searching for it) Also there is a suggestion to change the [date of the phone](http://www.journeybytes.com/2017/01/how-i-deleted-incomplete-system-updates.html) but this does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

5 min after asking the question, it stilled worked...

By setting the date to one month later and restarting the phone, the 3 gb temporary files disappeared. So it seems you have to try using different dates.